# Polynomial n variables differentiable on $\mathbb{R^n}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives, polynomials

How would I define a polynomial of $n$ variables? And how would I go on to prove that any polynomial in $n$ variables is differentiable on $\mathbb{R^n}$? (assuming this function is continuous on $\mathbb{R^n}$)

I'm struggling to find a formal definition and I assume I use the chain rule for the second part but other than that I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: You have no guesses as to what a polynomial could be in, say, $\mathbb R^2$?

Answer (score 2):

Aloizio's answer should already be enough (and you should accept it), but explicitly, we'd have $$p(x_1,\cdots,x_n) = \sum a_{i_1\cdots i_n} x_1^{i_1}\cdots x_n^{i_n}.$$Since $$\Bbb R^n \ni (x_1,\cdots,x_n) \mapsto x_i \in \Bbb R$$is differentiable for each $i$, it follows that $p$ is differentiable as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of a polynomial *function* (*) in $\mathbb{R}^n$ as a composition of multiplications and sums of the projections $\pi_i$ and constant maps (**).

That this is differentiable follows from differentiability of the projections and sums/products of differentiable functions.

(*) Sidenote - a polynomial of $n$ variables is not, in general, a polynomial function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$. It has a more "formal" character.

(**) Sidenote 2 - To give an explicit definition:

Define a *finite R-multi-index* $I$ to be an element of $\mathbb{R} \times \Bbb{N}^n$, and $M^I: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R} $ to be $M^I:=c \pi_1^{j_1} \cdots \pi_n ^{j_n},$ where $I=(c,j_1,\cdots, j_n)$ is a finite R-multi-index. Now, $f:\Bbb{R}^n \to \Bbb{R}$ is a *polynomial function*  if there exists a finite amount $N$ of finite R-multi-indices $I_i$ such that
$$f=\sum_{i=1}^N M^{I_i}.$$

(Note that this is equivalent to Ivo's formula, with the slight difference that we have a somewhat more explicit control over the summation index).